# Como chamar um formulário de outro projeto em Webforms?

Tags: c#, webforms

Tenho dois projetos Webforms um com autenticação e outro sem. Preciso chamar um formulário do projeto sem autenticação dentro a partir do projeto com  autenticação. Como faço?

Answer (score -1):

O melhor modo para isso acredito que seja o Response.WriteFile();

```
Response.Write("Please Login: <br>");
 Response.WriteFile("login.txt");
```

Da mesma forma que pode ser um arquivo pode ser uma URL.

Veja mais em https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dyfzssz9(v=vs.110).aspx